# Texture2D.GetData() returns different data

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm using the `Texture2D.GetData()` method to create a Tilemap. This always works the first time I execute it, but the second time the method simply returns other Colors, confusing the whole algorithm. I see absolutely no reason for this.

My code:

```
switch (KartenID)
{
    case 1: WasserKarte = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Karte/Karte1");
            break;
    case 2: WasserKarte = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Karte/Karte2");
            break;
    default:WasserKarte = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Karte/StandardKarte");
            break;
}

KARTE_BREITE = WasserKarte.Width;
KARTE_HOEHE = WasserKarte.Height;

Color[] c = new Color[KARTE_BREITE* KARTE_HOEHE];

WasserKarte.GetData<Color>(c);
//and so on...
```

I am really frustated by now. I can't really tell if the `Content.Load<>` returns a wrong Texture, but I don't think so. Its just the second time I'm running this code without restarting the application.

I would really appreciate help.

Comment: What do you mean with "the second time"? What are you doing with that `Color[]`? I can ensure you that `Load<>` and `Texture2D.GetData` work well, I've never had problems, so you are doing something wrong I think.

Comment: There are a number of things that can go wrong here and the code you provided does not have enough information. 

Is WasserKarte a Texture2D or one that inherits Texture2D?

What are the data types of KARTE_BREITE and KARTE_HOEHE?

Comment: Yeah I know something is wrong, I just can't figure out what. I process the Color[] afterwards, but that doesnt really matter.. I load the texture again, and reset the Color[]. Its like a execute GetData() again with the same parameter and get other Data.. 

WasserKarte is a normal Texture2D, and the both variables KARTE_BREITE, KARTE_HOEHE are plain ints.

Comment: Do you use `Texture.SetData` in your algorithm? Because if you change its value you are changing the original texture, too.

Comment: No, I dont use it on this Texture. The code is executed when game has to load another map, so it is executed multiple times during the runtime. Everything is fine the first time,but when i execute the same code again, the Color[] hast wrong colors, for example (0,0,139,255) instead of (0,0,255,255).

Comment: I think you need to show more code, I can't see anything wrong here. Why do you load the same texture different times? Can't you simply use the first `Color[]` that you are sure is right?

Answer (score 0):

Same texture should always return same color data. For example:

```
var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("img");
var clr = new Color[texture.Width*texture.Height];
texture.GetData(clr);
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("img");
var clr2 = new Color[texture.Width*texture.Height];
texture.GetData(clr2);
for (int i = 0; i < clr.Length; i++)
{
    if (clr[i] != clr2[i])
    {
        // never gets hit
        Console.WriteLine("Error - color {0} != color {1}", clr[i], clr2[i]);
    }
}
```

Since you didn't provide more code I can only assume, that you doing something not intentional to a texture at runtime. However there is a simple way to fix your problem and optimize the code at the same time. Create class for storing textures information, something like this:

```
class Resource
{
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public Color[] ColorData;
}

Dictionary<string, Resource> Resources;
```

Instead of calling Content.Load each time you need to get color information, read all textures that is used in the level, then assign texture identifiers and get color data for each texture only once. Later just reuse already loaded color data from resources:

```
var colorData = Resource["KartenID"].ColorData;
// do something with color data
```

Of course this is just very simple example of game resources management, you can write more sophisticated resources manger to meet your needs.